# Binding data to a GridView from a Object with child objects containing relevant fields

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a List of complex objects containing other objects within that I give as the data source to a gridview.(currently I'm using BoundFields for the columns). I need to bind data to the columns from the objects within at run time. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LINQ projection to flatten (denormalise) the entity graph. You can either create a new `ViewModel` type class, or alternatively bind to an anonymous class, something like this:

```
var viewList = (
   from entity in entityList
       select new
       {
           Field1 = entity.Field1,
           Field2 = entity.Relation.AnotherField,
           Field3 = entity.Field3 + entity.Relation.YetAnotherField
       }).ToList();
myGridView.DataSource = viewList;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Use `Field1`, `Field2` on the `GridView` properties for the data bindings.

**Edit**

The above projection, in Lambda syntax:

```
var viewList = entityList
    .Select(entity => new
       {
           Field1 = entity.Field1,
           Field2 = entity.Relation.AnotherField,
           Field3 = entity.Field3 + entity.Relation.YetAnotherField
       })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like the following:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="TemplatesGrid" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TemplateId" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Template Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Author">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("AppUser.FullName") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Where AppUser is an object contained within a Template.