# How to select data from multiple tables with LINQ (entities)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables and corresponding LINQ entities

- product
- order

order has a fk_product_id in the database which is linked to pk_product_id in table product

How can I write a method that returns data from both tables, so that I can hook it up to a repeater or gridview?

I found examples where people are writing joins, but I wonder if that's really necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With LINQ you can do something like this:

```
var results = from o in Order
              select new
              {
                  order = o,
                  product = o.Product
              };
```

Then feed that as a DataSource to your repeater, and then access it in an ItemTemplate or such like this:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("product.Name") %>' />
```

Comment: thanks, I get an error in the form like: ataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[DAL.Order, App_Code.1lysc8mu, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[DAL.Product, App_Code.1lysc8mu, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'product_name'.

Comment: Depending on the way you've generated your data model, you can check your generated .edmx file and find out what the property is named.

Comment: it's named after my database column name "product_name"

Comment: got it! It show up in my repeater, but the gridview is empty. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: No clue, haven't used GridView. Check if you can show it with a ListView or some other control.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the fields you want from the 2 different objects into a new 'flat' anonymous type. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264336/binding-data-to-a-gridview-from-a-object-with-child-objects-containing-relevant-f).

Answer (score 0):

Use db.orders.include("product").all();
While u had  define product entity in order class ...